# Multiple choice in model

Tags: python, django

```py
ANIMALS = (('dog','dog'), ('cat','cat'))

class Owner(models.Model):
    animal = models.Charfield(choices=ANIMALS, max_length=10)
```

My problem is how I can do if I have both ?

Comment: A many-to-many model relationship?

Comment: So you are suggesting to create a model for Animal and link with a ManytoMany field ?

Comment: If you have a better idea of how to store an arbitrary number of distinct predefined values in a single field of a database table entry, I am curious to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your best solution is to think about how you are going to store the data at a database level. This will dictate your approach and therefore your solution.
You want a single column that stores multiple values so your best approach would be to use [django-multiselectfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/)

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

MY_CHOICES = ((1, 'Item title 2.1'),
              (2, 'Item title 2.2'),
              (3, 'Item title 2.3'),
               (4, 'Item title 2.4'),
               (5, 'Item title 2.5'))

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = MultiSelectField(choices=MY_CHOICES,
                                 max_choices=3,
                                 max_length=3)
```

Comment: Thanks I wanted to keep my structure  and not add a model in db.

Comment: this won't work with Django 4.1.3 properly. Not recommended to use as the module is not actively maintained and has many serious issues.

Answer (score 0):

your need to have model like this:

```
class Choices(models.Model):
  animal = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Owner(models.Model):
    animal = models.ManyToManyField(Choices)
```